# Using apply or iterrows in python instead of groupby?

Tags: python

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[15000, 2015], [20000,2015], [25000,2015], [15000, 2016], [20000,2016], [25000,2016], [10500, 2017], [54000,2017], [34000,2017]], columns=['income', 'year'])


income          year
15000           2015
20000           2015
25000           2015
19000           2016
36000           2016
20000           2016
10500           2017
54000           2017
34000           2017
```

Hello,

If I have a dataframe like the one above and I want to loop through each year in python and create a median income value for each year, how would I go about it?

Would the apply function or the groupby function be best?

I can get this to work:

```
df.groupby(df.year)[['income']].median()
```

I was wondering whether there was an alternative such as apply or iterrows?

Many thanks.

Comment: `groupby` is absolutely the way to go for this, and most aggregation tasks. `apply` is for line-wise operations, and `iterrows` is usually to be avoided in favor of one of the two former methods.

Comment: Thanks :). As a follow up, how would I assign the output to a new variable to each respective case? So each case in 2017 has the median value for 2017 etc? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is the best way to go when you are doing certain aggregations.

This is the right way to use it:

```
In [85]: df.groupby('year', as_index=False)['income'].median()
Out[85]: 
   year  income
0  2015   20000
1  2016   20000
2  2017   34000
```

**After OP's comment:**

```
In [239]: res = df.groupby('year', as_index=False)['income'].median()
In [259]: d = res.set_index('year').to_dict()['income']
```

Then you can query the above `dict` d to get mean for a certain year, like this:

```
In [268]: d.get(2015)
Out[268]: 20000

In [269]: d.get(2016) 
Out[269]: 20000

In [270]: d.get(2017) 
Out[270]: 34000
```

Comment: Thanks :). As a follow up, how would I assign the output to a new variable to each respective case? So each case in 2017 has the median value for 2017 etc? Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Mayank. Will that give the output as part of a pandas data frame? Ideally I’d like to use it as a variable on a data frame. Cheers.

Comment: No, that gives you the output as a dictionary. You don't need individual variables. You can use the dictionary for that.